# Unable to send parameter from JSF to Bean through datatable value attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, rowexpansion

I have a expansion datatable which is being populated by an Arraylist from the backend which has an id as primary key. When row is expanded, that id specific rows has to be searched in an another table and all the rows has to be displayed. when I am trying to pass the id as parameter in the value attribute, it's giving class cast exception.

here's the XHTML Code

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="data"
        value="#{trackerList.trackerList}">
        <f:facet name="header">Summary</f:facet>
        <p:column style="width:16px">
            <p:rowToggler />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="ID">
            <h:outputText value="#{data.id}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Status">
            <h:outputText value="#{data.status}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Created Time">
            <h:outputText value="#{data.createdTime}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Created By">
            <h:outputText value="#{data.createdby}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Updated By">
            <h:outputText value="#{data.updatedby}" />
        </p:column>
        
        <p:rowExpansion>
            <p:dataTable var="metadata" value="#{statusList.getScenarioStatusList(data.id)}">
                <p:column headerText="Requirements">
                    <h:outputText value="#{metadata.requirements}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Exam Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{metadata.examName}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Status">
                    <h:outputText value="#{metadata.status}" />
                </p:column>
                
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to define below line inside the p:datatable tag with passing id as parameter and instead of #{statusList.getScenarioStatusList(data.id)} in sub datatable you just do value= "#{yourBean.scenarioStatusList}". populate scenarioStatusList in loadLists(data.id) method.

```
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{yourBean.loadLists(data.id)}"  />
```

Comment: Tried it out.. But still the same error persists... it's giving error for the listener method.. it's throwing java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.beans.ScenarioStatus exception when I am trying to print the list inside the loadList method.

Comment: It's working.. Actually the casting problem was in the DAO Class. Thanks for the help. :)